How to design a separate authorization server using the ROPC OAuth2 flow?
I am implementing a user management system where the user can register (using username and password), login and perform CRUD operations. The tech-stack that I am using to achieve this is django and graphQL. For the authorization, I am using the OAuth protocol.
The authorization server should be implemented separately from the client app. The auth server is responsible for authorization and the client app is responsible for the CRUD operations. They must communicate in apis to check if the user performing the CRUD operations bears the correct access token or not.
But I am facing trouble in separating the authorization part of the code from the CRUD operations.

Where do I store the user details once they register? Is it in the database linked with the authorization server or in the database linked with the client app or both?
And also how to communicate between two servers using graphQL. Should I create a view (in django) for the server 'A' and send a POST request using graphQL in the server 'B' to that corresponding view?

I wanna establish this scenario using graphQL for API calls ROPC OAuth Flow

The question is a bit unclear. Please clarify the specific problem you're facing with implementing the ROPC OAuth2 flow using Django and GraphQL.

Hey, I've edited my question. Could you please look into it?
